# Condensing multiple 'or' conditions in python

Tags: python

Let's say that I have multiple 2D arrays that need to be utilized for some boolean logic. For example:

```
q1 = np.array(data1 < 0)
q2 = np.array((data2 < -10) & (data1 > 5))
q3 = np.array(data3 > 10)
```

There are instances where some [x,y] will be the same for q1, q2, q3, and some instances not. I would like to use these conditions on another array. Such as:

```
a[q1] = -999
a[q2] = -999
a[q3] = -999
```

The problem is that this is a bit cumbersome and I would like to condense it into something like:

```
a[q1 or q2 or q3] = -999
```

But the above does not seem to work as intended. What is the best course of action to get the desired result?

Comment: Simple way: `for q in (q1, q2, q3): a[q] = -999` (a more efficient way may exist).

Comment: For code clarity, I'd avoid doing anything fancy.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the binary operator `|` for your "or" operation. Python's `or` is a keyword that does a different thing that can  only result in a single boolean value - and cannot be overriden by numpy to provide a series of index for a selector, like `&` and `|` can.

```
In [236]: import numpy as np

In [237]: aa = np.zeros(20, dtype="uint8")

In [238]: aa[:] = range(20)

In [239]: bb = aa % 3 == 0

In [240]: cc = aa % 5 == 0

In [241]: aa[bb | cc]
Out[241]: array([ 0,  3,  5,  6,  9, 10, 12, 15, 18], dtype=uint8)

In [242]: aa[bb | cc] = 255

In [243]: aa
Out[243]: 
array([255,   1,   2, 255,   4, 255, 255,   7,   8, 255, 255,  11, 255,
        13,  14, 255,  16,  17, 255,  19], dtype=uint8)
```